# Recover photos safely

Tags: data-recovery, photos

A friend had about 60 photos that were very important to her, because she is planning to use them in a lawsuit.

She wanted to upload the photos to Google Drive and then delete them from the phone, but apparently she deleted them before the upload was finished (only 3 photos were uploaded).

Is there a safe way to recover the deleted photos? From what I can read on the internet, there are apps such as DiskDigger that will help recover deleted files, but I am worried about something: if I start doing stuff on the phone which involves moving things in memory like installing new apps, am I not taking the risk that the photos will be "hard-erased"?

What should I do? Thank you for your advice.

Details:

- Phone is a Samsung with Android 4.42
- Application used to take/handle photos is Camera (Google Photos not installed)
- Memory used is internal memory. There is 142Mb free space available right now.

Comment: Every use of the device (especially taking more photos) reduces your chances of a successful recovery, yes. As this kind of question was asked a couple of times already, may I suggest you consult our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) while waiting for answers – and [edit] your post to include where the photos were stored (internal storage or external SD card), as that's important for the recovery approach?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll edit the question. I know similar questions were asked, I hope the specificity of my question is still worth asking.

Comment: "Internal storage" and "not rooted" makes it hard – as you would have to install something to access the file system for recovery (an SD card could be used via a card reader on a computer), and the installation would take place on the very same storage (ouch, only 142M free makes overwriting even more likely). I have [a list of recovery apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872) on my site you could check (and indeed, *DiskDigger* is in that list and well rated). Skip the "recycle bins", as they're no use for your situation.